# Proving that -(-v) = v

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that $-(-v) = v$. So far, this is my attempt: 
$$
-v + -(-v) = -1v + -(-1v) = v(-1 + -(-1)) = 0v = 0.$$ Thus, $-v + -(-v) = 0$, which implies that $-(-v) = v$.

Is that correct or does it need to be tweaked? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessarily incorrect, but it depends on what you have previously proven from your axioms.

In any case, it uses too many things. By definition, $-v+v=0$. That is, $-v$ is the (one can show unique) element $x$ such that $x+v=0$. But then the equation $-v+v=0$ can be read as $v+(-v)=0$, which shows that $v$ is the element that when added to $-v$ gives zero. Which means precisely that $-(-v)=v$.

In short, the equality $-v+v=0$ tells you that $-v$ is the additive inverse of $v$, and it also tells you that $v$ is the additive inverse of $-v$; this last statement  $-(-v)=v$.